# How to add a custom index by specific column value?

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with with 2 columns:id(of a movie) and actor_name. For each id, there can be multiple actor names.
I want to add a new column with an index specific for each actor.
My table look like this:
Id.......actor_name
5........Al pacino
6........Tim Roth
7........Antonio Banderas
8........Al pacino

And I want it to look like this:
Id.......actor_name..............actor_number
5........Al pacino.................. 1
6........Tim Roth....................2
7........Antonio Banderas......3
8........Al pacino...................1
I'm doing this in power BI. I have a table with each actor and a specific index, but I can't make the connection between them because I don't have unique values in the the actor_name column.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How many Actors do you have in that column?

Comment: In total they are 372348, but most of them can be found multiple times with other id.

Comment: Can you join on Actor_name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would resolve this in the Query Editor/ Power Query.  First I would build a query (lets call it **Actor Index**) by **Reference** to your "table with each actor and a specific index". I would either use **Remove Rows / Remove Duplicates** or **Group By** to ensure there are unique values for each actor_name.

Then over in your "My Table" query, I would add Merge and Expand steps to join to the new **Actor Index** and return the Index.